# Read data from txt file from a specific pattern in text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to extract data into dataframe from a text file, after a specific word was found
Here is an example of text file:

```
Signal:
197 198 180 140 
X_values:
11  26  8   15  
14  17  12  10  
** Exe Trs:
[115] time1: 1 (42 ms) - tou(): 4.7 - JH: 5 (B: 0)
[230] time2: 2 (87 ms) - tou(): 3.0 - Am: 5 (B: 0)
```

What I want is to have two dataframes created as below:

```
df1: 
    Signal  X_values1  X_values2
    197     11       14
    198     26       17
    180      8       12
    140     15       10

df2:
order   time(ms) 
115      42
230      87
```

Comment: Break the problem down. Look at the file to see if it has a predictable structure. Then search for working with text files that have a structure.  You may be looking to get parts of the file into lists, perhaps clean them up, and then join them into a frame.  If the files are short in length you may be able to get fairly simple regex to work.  If the files are really long you perhaps need to extract blocks and work on those individually.  SO isn't here to write code for you, but as a bit of food for thought and to know something is doable see this incomplete example: https://ideone.com/13nMht

Answer (score -1):

A quick solution is to use a regex if your files always follow the same order of the fields. If you want something more efficient/robust, you need to write a custom parser.

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

with open('your_file', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    
signal, values, exec_t = re.search('Signal:\n([\d ]+)\nX_values:\n([\d\n ]+)\n\*\* Exe Trs:\n([\w\W]*)',
                                   text).groups()

signal = re.split('\s+', signal.strip())
values = re.split('\s+', values.strip())
exec_t = re.findall('\[(\d+)][^(]+\((\d+) ms', exec_t)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(values).reshape(-1, len(signal)).T,
                   index=signal,
                   columns=['X_values%s' % (i+1) for i in range(len(values)//len(signal))]
                  ).rename_axis('Signal').reset_index()

df2 = pd.DataFrame(exec_t, columns=['order', 'time(ms)'])
```

output:

```
>>> df1
  Signal X_values1 X_values2
0    197        11        14
1    198        26        17
2    180         8        12
3    140        15        10

>>> df2
  order time(ms)
0   115       42
1   230       87
```

Comment: I didn't downvote although want to because answering questions like this only increases the likelihood of there being even more of them…and there's more than enough already.

Comment: @martineau a quick look at the other questions of this user gave me the feeling that, although not very good at asking questions, this is still a legitimate user.  I don't think we can do anything against poorly phrased questions, but we can try to turn them into useful answers (this is also what you did in editing the question to make it better).